# Old CD Where do I cash? Thirty + Years Old

Tags: united-states

I have a 32 year old CD, and access to tax records.The bank has no records, the original banks have closed due to mergers and the state has no record of escheat. How do I cash this CD or where can I cash it?

AJ

Comment: Have you tried your state's "lost money" service?  Most have them, and that can sometimes be more thorough than other methods of identifying things like this.  (If you don't know what i'm talking about, add the state tag and we can point you to it)

Comment: What documents are on this CD? Does it still work?

Answer (score 4):

Did you try the FDIC research site: https://research.fdic.gov/bankfind/
FDIC says this is the first stop to try to find closed/merged banks.